# in sailsjs , 403 "You don't have permission to see the page you're trying to reach" error produce when adding new pages ,controllers and models

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

First i run my sails project in local , after i pushed in git repo and then i  changed in online and then pushed in remote place. then i downloaded in my local. This changes produce permission problem. that is

```
"You don't have permission to see the page you're trying to reach"
```

this error caused while i was inserting data in mongo.
what i should do ? i want get output back

Comment: Pls, provide more information about your issue. For now, nothing is clear what is your actual problem and how do you get it.

Comment: i put one application in my server via git. i edited in my server terminal and then i pushed my repository.  In local , i pulled that files then i  added some extra pages , controllers and i  lifted my sails in local that produce "You don't have permission to see the page you're trying to reach" this error page. because of permission problem.

Comment: Maybe you have problems with the [routes](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes) of your application. Your problem is not clear...

Comment: try `sails lift` again after stopping it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess since I'm not sure what your code looks like but I'm guessing you haven't included the following CSRF line

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
```

inside your form which is doing the POST.